# JavaScriptInterface not added on API 18

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

I am using a WebView to execute some JS code in my app. This works fine so far on my KitKat (targetSdk) device, and also on a 2.2 (minSdk) emulator.
On a 4.3 Nexus 7 I encountered an error though. It seems as the JS object doesn't get injected.

`Uncaught ReferenceError: android is not defined at null:1`

Following a stripped down version of my code:

```
public void getData(Context ctx) {
    WebView webView = new WebView(ctx);
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(new AndroidInterface(), "android");
    webView.loadUrl("javascript:console.log(android.getInput());");
}

public class AndroidInterface {
    @JavascriptInterface
    public String getInput() {
        return "FOO";
    }
}
```

The JS itself gets executed fine, so doing `console.log('FOO');` prints FOO just as expected. But as soon as I try to access the interface I get the `ReferenceError`. Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Could be a number of things. You can try the following to narrow it down:

- insert a sleep (1sec is more than enough) between the add and the loadUrl. It's unlikely that the API is racey but it's easy to check.
- load a page before calling loadUrl("javascript:..."). Call something like `loadUrl("about:blank")` or `loadData("<p>foo</p>", ...);` and sleep for a bit.

Calling `loadUrl("javascript:...")` internally evaluates the JavaScript in the current page, it doesn't perform a 'real' navigation. It might be that the interface that you're adding is not being picked up by the context in which your `loadUrl("javascript:...")` call is executed (especially that the 'starting' page the WebView loads after being constructed is a bit special) and that performing a navigation makes the WebView "pick up" the newly added interface.

Comment: +1 That could very well be the cause. I wonder why it's only on API 18 then. Guess they chnaged something inbetween. I can't test it now anymore as I had to return the tablet in question. I can imagine though that loading a blank page could actually work as it's much the same of what I'm doing in my described workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround, would still be interesting to know why it doesn't work on 4.3.

So instead of using `loadUrl`, I surrounded the JS by a piece of HTML and used `loadData`.

```
webView.loadData("<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><script type=\"text/javascript\">function go(){console.log(android.getInput());}</script></head><body onload=\"javascript:go()\"></body></html", "text/html", "UTF-8");
```